# Auto resizable popups with scrolling bars

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, autoresize, modalpopups

I’m trying to create popups that has a header, body and footer, that resizes depending on the content and to a maximum depending on the viewable content from the browser (if you expand the browser, so does the popup and adjusts), and activate the scrolls when reached overflow of the declared `max-height: 80%`.

The problem is that, if I use `max-height`, the div that should be scrollable, does not apply and expands (see example).
If I change it to `height`, then the code works, but all popups have the same height, which is something I don’t want.

See code below (or in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrHeadSlash/hotL904u/0/)).

The second  popup that opens from the image, has the large text that needs scroll bars active and I have no idea how to get it to work:

```js
$(function() {
  //Variable used by ESC function
  var current_class = ""

  //----- OPEN on Click
  $('[dataPopup_open]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('dataPopup_open');
    $('[dataPopup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
    current_open_class = targeted_popup_class
    e.preventDefault();

    //Fix for selection issue. When text is selected and 
    //popup is shown, scroll bars will not work. 
    //This cancels any selection on current page.
    if (document.selection) {
      document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
  });

  //----- CLOSE Buttons in POPUP
  $('[dataPopup_close]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('dataPopup_close');
    if (e.target !== this) return;
    $('[dataPopup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    e.preventDefault();
    current_open_class = ""
  });

  //----- CLOSE with ESC
  //By pressing ESC and using declared active popup in "current_open_class", this will close active popup. This will not close all popups.
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $('[dataPopup="' + current_open_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Outer */

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Inner */

.popup-inner {
  /*max-width:700px;*/
  padding: 34px 0;
  /*padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  /*
    transition: top .25s ease;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    */
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}
.popup_padding {
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.popup_content {
  background: #cedde5;
  height: 100%;
}
.popup_content h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.pop_header_closeX {
  top: 0px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #acd0e2;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}
.pop_footer_close {
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #acd0e2;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}
/* Close Button */

.popup-close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  transition: ease 0.25s all;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 1000px;
  /*
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    */
  background: none;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
  /*
    color:#fff;
    */
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.popup-close:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  /*
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    */
  background: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST POPUP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popupCCS.css">
  <script src="..\js\jQueryV3.js"></script>
  <script src="popupJS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Bla Bla Title</h2>
      <p>
        <a class="btn" dataPopup_open="popup-1" href="#">Test POPUP 1</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        Test 1
        <ul>
          <li>
            Test pointer 1
          </li>
        </ul>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a class="btn" dataPopup_open="popup-2" href="#">Test POPUP 2</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        Test 2
        <ul>
          <li>
            Test pointer 1
          </li>
        </ul>
      </p>
      <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/3unhjb09x/Test_Image_Popup.jpg" usemap="#ImgPopupCoord">
      <map name="ImgPopupCoord">
        <area shape="rect" coords="12,1,83,59" dataPopup_open="popup-3" href="#">
        <area shape="rect" coords="39,109,67,123" dataPopup_open="popup-4" href="#">
      </map>
    </div>
    <div dataPopup_close="popup-1" class="popup" dataPopup="popup-1">
      <div class="popup-inner">
        <div class="pop_header_closeX">
          <a class="popup-close" dataPopup_close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
        </div>
        <div class="popup_content">
          <h2>Popup 1 OK</h2>
          <p>
            Test 1
            <ul>
              <li>
                Test pointer 1
              </li>
            </ul>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="pop_footer_close">
          <p>
            <a dataPopup_close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div dataPopup_close="popup-2" class="popup" dataPopup="popup-2">
      <div class="popup-inner">
        <h2>Popup 2 OK</h2>
        <p>
          Test 2
          <ul>
            <li>
              Test pointer 2
            </li>
            <li>
              Test pointer 2
            </li>
            <li>
              Test pointer 2
            </li>
            <li>
              Test pointer 2
            </li>
          </ul>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a dataPopup_close="popup-2" href="#">Close</a>
        </p>
        <a class="popup-close" dataPopup_close="popup-2" href="#">x</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div dataPopup_close="popup-3" class="popup" dataPopup="popup-3">
      <div class="popup-inner">
        <h2>Popup 3 Image OK</h2>
        <p>
          Test 3
          <ul>
            <li>
              TEST POPUP for GAOP's
            </li>
          </ul>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a dataPopup_close="popup-3" href="#">Close</a>
        </p>
        <a class="popup-close" dataPopup_close="popup-3" href="#">x</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div dataPopup_close="popup-4" class="popup" dataPopup="popup-4">
      <div class="popup-inner">
        <div class="pop_header_closeX">
          <a class="popup-close" dataPopup_close="popup-4" href="#">x</a>
        </div>
        <div class="popup_padding">
          <div class="popup_content">
            <h2>Popup 4 Image with SCROLL OK</h2>
            <p>
              Test 4
              <ul>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3Test pointer 3
                </li>
              </ul>
              <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop_footer_close">
          <p>
            <a dataPopup_close="popup-4" href="#">Close</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the popup to the size of the content? Would it not be preferable to set it to the height of the webpage?

Comment: Hi, well I explained incorrectly.
I've edited the text. The idea is to have the popups resize depending on their content to a maximum that I indicate that is regulated by the size of the page. 
The width works; it’s the height that I have an issue with.

Comment: Oh dear, this question has gotten into a right pickle! Please note that Stack Overflow is not a live code-editing website - we do not want questions being left in a state where the first statement is that they have been edited, since new readers (i.e. most readers) will not have seen the prior version. It looks like your several edits were incremental attempts towards an answer, so please collate those and put them *below*, so that the question-answer pair is preserved. I have rolled the question back to an earlier state.

Comment: Note that edits _are_ allowed to questions, as long as the question remains a question. If answers arrive when the question is in a particular state, the question should not be edited in a way that would invalidate the existing answers. Or if a question changes dramatically so that it is essentially another question, the new material should be added to a separate question. Finally, as per my earlier comment, answers belong below the question, so they make sense in the context of the question being asked.

Comment: Would that be ok?

Comment: No, answers belong in answers. Do you see the white editing box below the comments, where answers may be written? This is usually completed by other people, but we also accept self answers here. I should have explained this more explicitly, apologies `:-)`. Please roll back your latest edit and add it as an answer instead, thanks.

Comment: (Note that if your solution is simply a repeat of the existing answer, there is no value in writing it out again. However if you have built on top of the existing answer and you believe your solution would be useful to others, then we very much welcome that additional post. Lastly to reply to me, please use `@halfer` so that I get notified. Thanks).

Comment: Hi @halfer, i didn't take all its suggested answer, but parts that made it work. I still deem mr iMarketingGuy solution as the only solution (may it be partial or close to fully functional).
I've rolled it back right to the begining, even before I added the JS  and CSS that iMarketingGuy suggested initially.
`.popup-inner {
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.popup_padding {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 65vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css class "vh" to work with the screen dimensions. No need for javascript. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ygg9a1/1/) was forked from your latest link. Some changes were made such as:

<strike>jQuery</strike> (deleted)

CSS

```
.popup-inner {
    max-height: 70vh;
}

.popup_padding {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 65vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

.pop_header_closeX {
    top: -34px;
}

.pop_footer_close {
    bottom: -34px;
}
```

You may want to toy around with the positioning and sizing a little, especially via media queries for smaller displays, but this change definitely achieves what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code.
This would be ok, but it resized all popups to the maximum.
The idea is that, if there is a small text, thepopup box is small.
if there is text that occupies more than what can fit on the screen depending on the indicated maximum's, then a scroll bar should appear.  
(80% width and height so there is some separation and doesn’t take up the whole screen)
Your solution would just maximize the popups.

Comment: I added a class to the HTML and changed the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the code.
The code would work, but for that specific popup.  It would not work for all popups.
Then there is `overflow:auto`  that would cause the inner div to have a scroll bar (not my intention).
See example with & without overflow:auto in your code.
With:https://jsfiddle.net/MrHeadSlash/hotL904u/11/ and Without:https://jsfiddle.net/MrHeadSlash/hotL904u/12/ 
Removing that, your code still works and the scroll bars only appear for the `popup_padding` (the container of the body).
Click on Test POPUP 1 to see the difference. If used on all popups, all have same height.

Comment: there was another last minute edit to the js... height was changed to max-height. It works but the close bar in the footer of the popout isn't staying fixed to the bottom at the moment...

Comment: Awesome, I’ve edited a bit so it only effects the popup_padding instead of the `popup-inner` (see jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/MrHeadSlash/hotL904u). The only issue now is that when popup opened, the popup doesn't resize if windows is resized. Is there a way to actively resize the popup?

Comment: Nice! Add overflow:hidden to .popup_inner and you might be good to go

Comment: Then again... when it gets really small, you lose the scrollbar because it's associated with the padding, not it's parent div; popup_inner...

Comment: Alright man ... lol . I made one last attempt to get the desired outcome. You're more than welcome to check mark the new code above as an accepted answer ; )  Happy coding.

Comment: Awesome. I was actually going to say OK to the entry before, but this is much better. I totally missed the CSS properties for vh and vw.

The only thing i didn't change is the top and bottom for the header and footer. As is, works fine. (unless you changed something else and needs that value)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.